# Screencapturer for Mac, Webrtc leaves impressions of closed menu

Tags: webrtc, screen-capture, openwebrtc

Using desktop capturer in mac, leaves a impression when menu is closed. attached screenshot. The impression is majorly visible on a black background

[image: Sample Screenshot]